# label_binarize classes without losing index number

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am trying to binarize a target class without losing the index number. However, failed and could not find the corresponding option in sklearn.preprocessing.label_binarize.
input y:

```
index  target
 1      0
 3      0
 21     1
 50     1
```

code:

```
y=data['target']
y=label_binarize(y, classes=[0, 1])
y=np.hstack((1-y, y))
```

output:

```
    0    1
0   1    0
1   1    0
2   0    1
3   0    1
```

the output I prefer

```
    0    1
1   1    0
3   1    0
21   0    1
50   0    1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scikit-Learn functions accept Pandas dataframe as input, but they **return numpy array as result**. You should consider this rule while working with dataframes.

Therefore `y` is a numpy array. However you can make it dataframe again like this:

```
y = pd.DataFrame(y, index=data.index)  # make it dataframe, and pass data indices
y.head()
```

Now, `y` is:

```
    0   1
1   1   0
3   1   0
21  0   1
50  0   1
```